# Load csv file and add values every 10 lines

Tags: r, oop, parsing, csv

i would like to do the average of values every 10 lines, but i have a small problem my values in the csv are like that :

```
 a,b,c,d
 1,2,5,1.5
 1,3,6,2.5 
 1,4,8,4.5
 1,5,4,7.5
 1,8,2,8.5
```

I did a small function to resolve that,with a,b,c i get the good result but with d i get 0.

I get this 0 because my program cannot add 2 values separated by "." ,if it was a "," it will work perfectly.But the comma here is used to separate values of the csv file.

I don't know how to figure out for this problem

Thank you.

All your solution work.

I have another question for the same problem ,how can i do the same thing with getter , for example :

I have the class Test and when i do the getter test["d"] i will have that :

```
An object of class "Test"
Slot "val":
[1] 35.9 35.9 35.9 35.9 35.9
```

How can i do it ?

Thank you again

Comment: You may want to update the title to your post since it's not actually a calculation issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to change `"."` to `","`

```
> # dat <- read.csv(text = "a,b,c,d
 # 1,2,5,1.5
 # 1,3,6,2.5 
 # 1,4,8,4.5
 # 1,5,4,7.5
 # 1,8,2,8.5")
> dat$d <- gsub("\\.", ",", as.character(dat$d))
> dat
#   a b c   d
# 1 1 2 5 1,5
# 2 1 3 6 2,5
# 3 1 4 8 4,5
# 4 1 5 4 7,5
# 5 1 8 2 8,5
```

Not sure what your machine will do with the class of column `d`, but on mine it becomes a character vector. To coerce it directly to numeric, try

```
dat$d <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.", ",", as.character(dat$d)))
```

in place of the `dat$d <- gsub(...` line in the chunk above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you sample data doesn't even have 10 rows, so i'll group every three rows. I'll do this by making a fake group varible

```
#sample input
dd <- data.frame(
    a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    b = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 8), 
    c = c(5, 6, 8, 4, 2), 
    d = c(1.5, 2.5, 4.5, 7.5, 8.5)
)

#grouping variable for every three lines
grp<-(seq.int(nrow(dd))-1) %/% 3 + 1

#use aggregate to calculate mean for groups
aggregate(.~grp, dd, mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just.

```
data1=read.table(header=TRUE,sep=",",text="a,b,c,d
1,2,5,1.5
1,3,6,2.5 
1,4,8,4.5
1,5,4,7.5
1,8,2,8.5")

data1
  a b c   d
1 1 2 5 1.5
2 1 3 6 2.5
3 1 4 8 4.5
4 1 5 4 7.5
5 1 8 2 8.5
```

Comment: "I get this 0 because my program cannot add 2 values separated by "." ,if it was a "," it will work perfectly."